# Empty vue prop causes compilation to fail

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a Vue component that looks like this:

```
<review :rating="<?= $reviewAverage ?>"></review>
```

The `reviewAverage` is either an int or set to null. When it is set to null the component does not receive a value and the entire compilation fails:

> [Vue warn]: failed to compile template:

Although this can be attributed to user error on my part for not checking the value with a wrapping `if` statement it a real problem when the entire page suddenly turns white.

Is there any thing that can be done to prevent this behavior from happening? The component itself breaking it not that big of a deal to me, at least as I do not get a blank page.

Comment: What is this syntax `<?= $reviewAverage ?>` ???

Comment: you are using a php variable to a javascript(vue.js) instance.I dont think it can be done.Because the :rating will look for a string so to pass 'something',or will look for a property in that component.

Comment: I see you on `Laravel-Mix` repo. I assume that you are using Laravel, why are you not using blade? If you are, use `@{{ reviewAverage }}`

Comment: You can use operator `if` in small form: `$result = $condition ? 'if true' : 'if false'`. Code sample: `<review :rating="<?= $reviewAverage ? $reviewAverage : 0 ?>"></review>`

Comment: @RuChernChong A verbatim directive is not going to change anything, it will still break on a `null` value. Changing this to an inline solution is obviously is also not workable in the long run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to make sure that `:rating=""` won't occur. `<?= null ?>` would output nothing.

So how about setting it to an empty string if it's null

```
<review :rating="<?= $reviewAverage !== null ? $reviewAverage : '' ?>"></review>
```

if it's null, this would be the generated html

```
<review :rating="''"></review>
```